# Github Actions: Running a Bash Script

Tags: bash, github, github-actions

I am trying to run scripts from Github Actions and it keeps saying: No file or directory found.

This is the github action:

```
name: Build And Deploy
on:
  push:
#     branches:
#       - master`

jobs:
  generate-build-number-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-number-generator
      - name: Generate build number
        uses: einaregilsson/build-number@v3
        with:
          token: ${{secrets.github_token}}

      - name: Print new build number
        run: echo "Build number is $BUILD_NUMBER"
  
      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-2

      - name: Print GITHUB_WORKSPACE
        run: echo ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}

      - name: Build Docker
        run: |
             chmod +x "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/../docker/build-docker.sh"
             ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/../docker/build-docker.sh
      - name: Push Docker
        run: |
             chmod +x "${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/../docker/push-docker.sh"
             ${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/../docker/push-docker.sh
```

For some reason the `GITHUB_WORKSPACE` has weird path and thats why i have to do `${GITHUB_WORKSPACE}/../docker/push-docker.sh`, add `../` in the path. Is there a way to list the files or get the current working directory to look where the files actually are located?

I tried doing `echo ${cwd}` and `echo ${pwd}` but it echos nothing.

I have referenced the following link for running bash script:
https://github.community/t/running-a-bash-script/141584

Comment: `$PWD` is the Bash variable which contains the current directory; or run the `pwd` command.

Comment: Is `echo cd` a typo?

Comment: Doing `chmod +x` inside the action is kind of clumsy. Set the permissions in the repo, or explicitly run `bash path/to/script` which only requires read permission on the file.

Comment: Yes, it was a type. fixed it. i tried running the pwd command but it doesnt do anything. i will try running using ```bash path/to/script```.

Comment: is there a way to list the files in the PWD?

Comment: The command for that is `ls`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue was directory structure. Once i listed the files in the directory and found the path to the files, the action ran successfully. Here is the final yml script.

```
on:
  push:
     branches:
       - master

jobs:
  generate-build-number-deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
      # required for accessing files in repository.

      # https://github.com/marketplace/actions/build-number-generator
      - name: Generate build number
        uses: einaregilsson/build-number@v3
        with:
          token: ${{secrets.github_token}}

      - name: Print new build number
        run: echo "Build number is $BUILD_NUMBER"

      - name: Configure AWS credentials
        uses: aws-actions/configure-aws-credentials@v1
        with:
          aws-access-key-id: ${{ secrets.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID }}
          aws-secret-access-key: ${{ secrets.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY }}
          aws-region: us-east-2

      - name: Build Docker
        run: ${PWD}/docker/build-docker
      - name: Push Docker
        run: ${PWD}/docker/push-docker
```

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to run your commands with `working-directory:`  for those steps to make them execute in a certain directory - relative to your root folder.

Comment: is there a way to list all the file in the current directory, in github actions? for example do: ```echo ls -a``` in any directory?

Comment: @RajanShah you can do `echo "[LS]: $(ls -al)"`